# MongoDB - Find and return all the items of an array in each document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

so I have this system where users can input tags, but i want to add suggestions/auto-complete with dynamic data from all the previous tags in the database.

Here's what the data looks like:

```
    collection = [
      {
        title: "Avengers",
        tags:["si-fi", "powers", "super-heroes", "iron-man"],
        ...
      },
      {
        title: "Lego Movie"
        tags:["spider-man", "bottle", "man of steel"],
        ...
      }
      ...
    ]
```

So I want to retreive an array of all the tags that match a search string.

For example, if I search with `'man'`, I want the data returned to be:

```
[
  "iron-man",
  "spider-man",
  "man of steel"
]
```

Comment: The example you gave is of a collection or it is an array field of some document?

Comment: @AnandUndavia it is of a collection. Thanks

Comment: Just to be sure, `{ title: "Avengers", tags:[], ... }` is a document, right?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it cannot be done by direct querying. The following aggregation can do,

```
    db.collection.aggregate([{
        $unwind: '$tags'
    }, {
        $match: {
            'tags': { $regex: 'man' }
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            tags: { '$addToSet': '$tags' }
        }
    }]);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It did. Thanks!

Comment: RaR do you also know how I can limit the results to only 20. (For memory management)